# Modifying form values onSubmit but hide from user

Tags: javascript

Im attempting to modify a JAvascript login form. The form action calls a DLL so I cant modify it to include the modifications I want to make.

Here is the javascript function Im using:

```
function SubmitForm() {
    var Domain = "@domain.com"
    var txtBox = document.getElementById('username');

    if(txtBox.value.indexOf("\\") != -1){
        return; 
    }
    if((txtBox.value.indexOf("@") == -1) && (txtBox.value != "")) {
        txtBox.value += Domain;
        return;
    }   
}
```

Basically checks the username for \ and @ chars first, if it doesnt contain those values it adds the Domain to the username.

Ive added this to the `<form> onsubmit="return(SubmitForm());"` to calls and use this function. However I dont want the user to see the domain been added to the username.

Is there any other way to do this>

Answer (score 3):

Don't modify the input box, then. Rather have the `onSubmit` handler write whatever you want into a `type="hidden"` field which is used instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you absolutely can't change this on the server side, you could always change the ID of your `username` input field, and create a hidden field with an ID of `username` that you can populate with the user's input plus your domain.